# Accidental Community Wiki Entries

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

Any thoughts on putting an "Are you sure?" kind of pop-up related to the community wiki checkbox? I'm pretty sure I accidentally checked the box when I answered a question. Not entirely sure, but the message corresponds with the time of my answer. I didn't mean for it to be checked, but (a) I have no way of knowing after I submitted it if it was me who did it, and (b) the content is not really community wiki content.

Thoughts on that?

Comment: There should definitely a warning popup for low-rep users.

Comment: Only diamonds and above can instantly force a post to become CW, and they will be marked as the source of the status change. If it overlaps with the time of your answer, then you manually set it to CW. @KennyTM Actually, below a certain reputation threshold users don't even *get* the CW checkbox.

Comment: @Grace: [The](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3655209/revisions "59") [threshold](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3659766/revisions "11") [is](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3628283/revisions "8") [too](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3641146/revisions "6") [low](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3656270/revisions "1") [then](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3655986/revisions "1").

Comment: @Kenny That last example seems to strongly imply that the old threshold has been completely removed. I'm unsure what to say.

Answer (score 9):

A better idea would be to allow to un-wikify a post within 5 minutes. Kinda like you can revert votes, for a window of time.

Comment: That would be helpful, too, but in this case I didn't even know I'd marked it until a few hours later.

Comment: Maybe there should be some way a moderator could un-wikify it?

Answer (score 7):

If you realized immediately you accidentally checked it, you can always delete the post and re-submit it as a non-CW post.